# Mantener State de una mutación después de refrescar la pagina (VUEX)

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Hola tengo una duda enorme! estoy trabajando con Vuex y estoy tratando de personalizar la interfaz del usuario dinamicamente,es decir guardar propiedades del tema directamente en la base de datos para que el usuario pueda personalizar a su gusto y mantener sus cambios pero me surge un problema y es que al guardar las propiedades en un state funciona perfecto, pero al recargar la pagina el state se pierde y regresa la interfaz a su estado predeterminado, ¿podría guardar las propiedades sin que se pierdan al refrescar la pagina?

```
// ACTION PARA INICIAR SESION

loginJWT({ commit }, payload) {
      
      //LLAMADA AL SERVIDOR
      return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        jwt.login(payload.userDetails.email, payload.userDetails.password)
          .then(response => {

            // Si hay datos del usuario en respuesta
            if(response.data.userData) {

              // Establecer accessToken
              localStorage.setItem("accessToken", response.data.accessToken)

              // Actualizar los detalles del usuario
              commit('UPDATE_USER_INFO', response.data.userData, {root: true})

              // Almacena en el estado el tema del usuario
              if(response.data.settings.theme){
                  commit('UPDATE_THEME', response.data.settings.theme, {root: true})

              }

              router.push(router.currentRoute.query.to || '/')

              resolve(response)
            }

          })
          .catch(error => { reject(error) })
      })
    },
```

Pense como solucion almacenarlo en el Local Storage pero no me gusta que los usuarios tengan acceso a modificarlo directamente en el navegador y si hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo estaria mejor, espero puedan orientarme

Comment: estas modificando los states? deberias modificarlos en el mutation